# По какому правилу стоит тире?

Tags: пунктуация

По какому правилу ставится тире в предложении: *Она его так и называла - "повелитель"?* И какой член предложения слово "повелитель"?

Comment: Татьяна, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы, нажимая стрелочку (треугольник) вверх. Также один из ответов можно отметить галочкой, как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему. Пока у Вас нет ни одного принятого ответа.

Comment: Я за все ответы благодарила. (Просто словами). А на этот вопрос ответов нет пока...

Comment: Конечно, я видел это в комментариях, и очень хорошо, что Вы так делаете. Просто было удивительно, что за два с половиной года Вы как будто так и не обратили внимания на систему поощрения, хотя сами получали зелененькие десятки за вопросы. Думаю, отвечающим спустя время приятно будет увидеть по 10 и 15 баллов к своей репутации.

Comment: Вы правы - не обращала внимания на систему поощрений. Уж простите, меня это меньше всего интересует...Да и вопросы читаю нечасто. Но Ваши замечания приму к сведению. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

#### Почему стоит тире

Рассмотрим сначала этот вопрос. Предложение можно перефразировать, немного поменяв местами слова: "Она его называла так – повелитель". И хотя это предложение звучит странно, в нем легко задать соответствующие вопросы:

- Называла *(как?)* так
- Называла так *(как именно?)* — повелитель

Получается, *повелитель* – приложение.

> 10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:
>
> 1. если перед приложением можно вставить слова а именно (без изменения смысла): В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно — огонь квартиры Серафимы (Ж. Г.); Она зарисовала древние светильники с гербом города Ольвии — орлом, парящим над дельфинами (Пауст.); На суховатом лице Нечаева, с мягким мальчишеским лбом, остались следы ожогов — два белых незагорающих пятна (Н. Чук.)

([пп. 1. п. 10 §19](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111) у Розенталя)

#### Какой член предложения

Здесь у меня два варианта.

1. Раз уж мы выяснили, что повелитель здесь – приложение, то посмотрим на определение приложения:

> Приложе́ние (аппозитив) — определение, выраженное существительным...

(определение из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)))

То есть это определение *(волнистая линия)*

2. Если опять же перефразировать предложение, получим: `Она называла его повелителем`, где *повелитель* – очевидное дополнение. Однако так сильно менять изначальное приложение (что даже изменился падеж обсуждаемого слова) мне кажется неправильным, поэтому первый вариант выглядит более правдоподобным.

Comment: Единственное, в чем я не уверен, так это в том, что повелитель -- это вообще приложение, потому что стандартные примеры приложения все же отличаются от этого использования. Если окажется, что я не прав, я, конечно, удалю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим! Мне тоже странно, что это слово - приложение. Оно никак не подходит под эту категорию. Если приложение, то понятно, почему тире. Но... остаются сомнения...